# Automatic fallback from \fussy to \sloppy

Tags: line-breaking

1. If I activate `\sloppy` document-wide, will the paragraphs that render well with `\fussy` be affected?
2. If answer to the above is yes, is it possible to have `\fussy` by default, but automatically enforce `\sloppy` for paragraphs that give overfull `\hbox` warning with `\fussy`?

[A fussy-sloppy example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241343/65072)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer to [the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241355/1090), this is basically achieved by *not* using `\fussy` which sets `\tolerance` so affects all paragraphs, but by just setting `\emergencystretch` which only affects paragraphs that would otherwise have had over full lines.