# Fix Overfull Line in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, line-breaking

I have an overfull line in my bibliography (BibLaTeX) that I can't get rid of, see the image below.
I would assume that this behavior is caused by the hyphenated double word "Password-Scrambling".

For long URLs I have managed to properly break the lines using the following commands, where a high penalty value is defined for URL characters:

```
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}% Lowercase
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}% Uppercase
```

However, I cannot find anything about how I could get this hyphenated word to correctly break.

Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: The second answer using `\emergencystretch` before the bibliography did the trick, thank you.

Comment: The underlying problem here is that TeX only hyphenates words containing hyphens at the hyphen. So 'Password-Scrambling' can only be hyphenated at the `-`. All other hyphenation points of 'password' and 'scrambling' are ignored. That makes it hard to find a good place to line-break. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63232/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706/35864

Comment: Line breaking is hard and especially hard to get right in the bibliography, so usually solutions have to be specific to your situation. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864 gives a survey of possibly tricky situations and discusses specific and general solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the `\emergencystretch` command before the bibliography is printed.

This was one of the proposed answers here: [Overfull hbox using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161024/overfull-hbox-using-biblatex)

```
\emergencystretch 2em
\printbibliography
```